# How can I create a lowercase checker?

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble understanding how this recursion works, for example, if I want to make a `String -> Boolean` exercise to know if the string has a lower case in it how can i do it?This is my big amateur code, thats not even running the list properly, although I don't know any better:

```
lowercase (x:xs) | isLower x lowercase xs = True
                 | otherwise = False
```

Comment: You should read up on the syntax for guards (see the section on "Defining Basic Functions" [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall14/spring13/lectures/01-intro.html)). The expression between the `|` and `=` should evaluate to a boolean, and the expression to the right of the `=` should be the result of the function if the expression on the the left evaluates to true. The guard expressions will be tested starting from the top and moving downward until a `True` condition is found. Are you still confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good idea, but bad syntax.

```
lowercase :: String -> Bool
lowercase [] = True -- this case is needed to ensure that recursion stops
lowercase (x:xs) | isLower x = lowercase xs
lowercase _ = False
```

Or, using standard library,

```
lowercase = all isLower
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
lowercase (x:xs) = if isLower x
                     then lowercase xs
                     else False
```

But you still need to cover the empty string case:

```
lowercase [] = ???
```

Also note that there is no need to test if a boolean equals True or False explicitly. I.e. instead of `if boolexpr == True ...` just use `if boolexpr ...`

Comment: Further, `if x then y else False` can be written `x && y`.